# How do I find the phase of a transfer function in different ways?

Tags: transfer-function, phase

Suppose there is a transfer function

[image]

Now try to find the phase of this transfer function.

The phase can be expressed in different forms:

[image]

But each of these forms leads to a different result in the phase calculation:

[image]

So which one(s) of the above calculations is(are) correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Number 1: In your original expression there is no minus sign. It suddenly appears when you start calculating phase angles.
Number 2: All those expressions are equivalent and do yield the same phase. Your error is in misinterpreting the minus sign. Your first calculation (in black) is correct. Note that if there had been no minus sign, the first term would be positive which is a difference of π or 180 degrees which is the effect of multiplying by -1. In your second equation (the first red one), the minus sign again creates a phase of -π (not multiplying the phase by -1, which, when added to your expression, will result in the same expression as your first calculation. In your third calculation, moving the -1 to the denominator , adds a phase of π to the expression, and also results in the same result as your first equation. I will leave it as an exercise to figure out the correct interpretation of the minus signs.

Comment: Thanks, Barry. I have re-done the calculations. I have posted my corrections in the next answer. Could you please comment? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

For the third equation, it seems that the 3pi/2 term does match.

[image]